# Universal Windows Platform C# cannot edited with designer

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I develop with Windows 10 and Visual Studio C #.
I'm trying the tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-uwp-csharp?view=vs-2017

Target version 16299
The designer does not work: no graphical display in designer page, only xaml code.
What is wrong: target version ?
Thank for helping

Comment: Is that you can't find the designer , or, you've found it but it doesn't work?

Comment: I think that the designer is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS Build Number is need to be equal or greater than your windows development SDK version if you want to see the designer in visual studio during you development of Universal Windows Application.

To see windows version and build number open run with ***Windows+R*** and write ***winver*** then press enter, see the OS Build like below in my system.

[image]

So check your OS Build Number and it must be equal or greater that your target framework in order to let you see elements in your designer.

Comment: OK for the OS build version (I have 1803 17134). How can I have the SDK version number ?

Comment: @jlalexie check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665755/how-can-i-determine-the-version-of-the-windows-sdk-installed-on-my-computer)

Comment: After testing all versions, only the version target "Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0 Build 15063)" makes XAML Designer working.
 Strange !!

Comment: @jlalexie Maybe, your hardware environment doesn't meet the SDK running requirement. E.g, if your machine doesn't have enough ram, it will cause this issue.